# Diff between MoonMail / moonmail-models

Tags: moonmail

Is there a reason we can find this code in moonmail-models:

```
userId: _joi2.default.string().required(),
body: _joi2.default.string().required(),
subject: _joi2.default.string().required(),
name: _joi2.default.string().required(),
id: _joi2.default.string().required(),
senderId: _joi2.default.string(),
listIds: _joi2.default.array(),
sentAt: _joi2.default.number(),
createdAt: _joi2.default.number(),
scheduledAt: _joi2.default.number(),
status: _joi2.default.string(),
isUpToDate: _joi2.default.boolean(),
template: _joi2.default.string()
```

But there is no equivalent in MoonMail's s-resources-cf.json:

```
"CampaignsTable": {
  "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
  "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
  "Properties": {
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "id",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "userId",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "sentAt",
        "AttributeType": "N"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "scheduledAt",
        "AttributeType": "N"
      }
    ]
    }
}
```

Where is the body and subject stored in the DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the code to store the campaign data check out this file https://github.com/microapps/moonmail-models/blob/master/src/models/campaign.js

"Is there a reason we can find this code in moonmail-models?"

Yes it implies before saving the data it will validate the data you pass to dynamodb with the schema of the table

" this._validateSchema(schema, campaign) && campaign.status === 'draft'; "

The data from the api controllers is passed to moonmail models and for each table there is a file in

https://github.com/microapps/moonmail-models/blob/master/src folder those files extends Model.js
which handles URD - Update, Read and Delete operations on DynamoDB

Comment: Exactly! I would add that the code in `s-resources-cf.json` is the specification of the DynamoDB table, which requires to state only all the fields involved in an index, although you can save as many other fields as you want

Comment: @davids its as per your requirements, schema validation is necessary since it reduces DynamoDb query errors. DynamoDB has strict datatype validations it will throw errors if data type is not matched.